# C - Saving to file crashes

Tags: c, file, crash, save

```
    FILE *dataScore;
    dataScore = fopen(fileName.dat, "w");
    fprintf(dataScore,"%s:%d\n",currentUser,score);
    fclose(dataScore);
```

The file crashes on the line printing to file. I believe it is due to the username but I may be wrong. Thanks in advance. Set the currentUser as 02heasam and score as 20.

Comment: `currentUser = 02heasam;` isn't exactly valid C to begin with...

Comment: @Marc B I know, it was there for example. I've just thrown it outside the code for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks crazy...

try this way:

```
int score=20;

int main(void){   

    char* currentUser = "02heasam";

    FILE *dataScore;
    dataScore = fopen("fileName.dat", "w");

    fprintf(dataScore,"%s:%d\n",currentUser,score);
    fclose(dataScore);

}
```

some explanations:

- to fill a char array with a string you would need strcpy or so. Not needed here!
- the order might be important (declaration before usage)
- a strimng literal "xxx" will automatically terminated by a trailing 0-Byte - NEVER miss to have this in mind!